# GSS-API MSSQL JDBC Driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Has anyone found a JDBC Driver that supports GSS-API for MSSQL. I need to connect to a sql server using windows authentication. The fun part is it's the user logged into the application via JAAS not the user the application is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Not a java geek, but I thought jTDS supported windows authentication NTLM?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [DataDirect drivers](http://www.datadirect.com/products/jdbc/index.ssp) include a type-4 driver for SQL Server that supports GSSAPI.  We have tested them with our [Quest Single Sign-on for Java](http://www.quest.com/Single-Sign-On-for-Java/) product which provides comprehensive support for Windows authentication for J2EE and Java applications, and supports this sort of end-to-end delegation model you are using.